# Does it make sense?

Tags: functions

If $(f-g)(a)=0$, then $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ must be equal.

I need to determine if this statement makes sense or not and write a defense of the argument. Can anyone help?

Comment: well, this depend on the codomain of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: How is the difference function $f-g$ defined? What is $(f-g)(a)$ by the definition? And then, what does it mean for it to be $0$?